# Do we need a tag for every genre?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed a new tag today: [dark-fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-fantasy). Essentially, according to the description, it is for questions about books that mix [fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) and [horror](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror).

My question is why do we need a tag for every genre specifically considering we aren't doing worldbuilding so genres shouldn't impact things *too* much (unless it is something super specific to [fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/36115/whats-the-name-of-the-trope-that-means-fae-cant-cross-over-unless-a-human-cros)  or science [fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/35729/referencing-modern-pop-culture-in-science-fiction) for example). I understand the purpose of high level genres like [romance](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance), [fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy), and [science-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction), but when we start adding very specific ones like [dark-fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-fantasy), I get a bit confused. Are we going to add tags for things like [alternate-history](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-history) and [cyberpunk](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyberpunk)? If we are, I think that's fine, I just think we should discuss the tag situation a bit more before adding a bunch of under utilized tags.

Comment: I added the tag because before it was just [tag:dark] used together with [tag:fantasy]. The tag existed before and was used like this before, only that previously it was less specific because someone didn't put a hyphen between the two words when writing his question and then it got used like that.

Comment: @Secespitus I assumed that's why. Thanks for mentioning it, I am simply concerned about continuation of this and not saying that this  was wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think we need tags that are that specific. While some of us write in a specific genre (I write speculative fiction, for instance - that's fantasy, sci-fi, and anything in between), most questions are not that specific. If I ask about a trope, if I ask about style, if I ask about planning the story - most of those questions would be general enough to go under broader tags than the specific genre, since those problems are fairly universal across fiction genres.

I can imagine questions that are specific to a particular genre, like [romance](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance) or [fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy). But I cannot imagine a question that's so specific to a particular sub-sub-genre that it would be irrelevant to the broader genre.

Tags exist to facilitate finding relevant questions (and answers). They also exist so people who are knowledgeable about a particular topic might be aware of new questions that they can answer. A tag that's too specific subverts both those goals.

Answer (score 5):

I share your concern; tagging questions into categories that are *accurate* but also *not helpful* is not the neatness we're looking for. As [Galastel says](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1576/1046), tags that are too specific aren't helpful.

As many other things in Stack Exchange, I hesitate to have a firm ruling -- it's hard to predict how the site may be used and what questions may arise; it's *conceivable* that we build up a serious body of questions that's specific to a subgenre, and then I'd support the tag.

But what I *wouldn't* do is try to "make it happen," to forcefully create subgenre tags. For example, the new [dark-fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-fantasy) tag, at the moment, only has three questions. Two are "what are some common tropes for dark (fantasy/romance)" questions (one closed, and not even about dark fantasy). One is a question about authentically writing depictions of brutal social norms in historical/fantastical settings, specifically trying to *avoid* writing a "dark" story; this re-tagging seems outright incorrect to me, and I'll be amending it.

I bring this instance not as a personal criticism, but as an example of judging the appropriateness of a tag. Hypothetical questions that *could* merit a [dark-fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-fantasy) tag, or another specific subgenre tag, might be things like:

- Dark Fantasy:

  - How far can I go in a YA Dark Fantasy
  - Will a happy ending to a dark fantasy disappoint readers
- Urban fantasy: Questions on customizing popular urban fantasy tropes (vampires; werewolves; witches; etc.) for your particular book/story
- Alternate history:

  - Questions about getting across what the story's historical deviation has been
  - Questions about making clear what elements are historical and which are not
  - Questions about making a story accessible even to readers unfamiliar with the actual history the story deals with

So I could definitely see subgenre tags *hypothetically* being useful, but I think a lot of the trick is simply not to rush forward and create *ever* hypothetically-useful tag.